# Accessing class properties after assignment returns undefined

Tags: javascript, class, properties

I have a problem accessing the class properties after I call the `updateUIFromDatabase()` function.

`Console.log` says "`startUpCount:  undefined`".

Before that, everything seemed to work (database returns `123` as it should when I call `pump1.getValueFromDatabase("startUpCount")`).

Edit: In Developer tools, at the response tab i can see the expected response(123), but `pump1.getValueFromDatabase("workingHours");` indeed returns undefined.

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong please?

```
class PumpBasic
{
    constructor(_name, _databaseTableName)
    {
        this.name = _name;
        this.databaseTableName = _databaseTableName;
        this.control = 0;
        this.statusOfPump = 0;
        this.feedback = 0;
        this.motorPTC = 0;
        this.dryRunProtection = 0;
        this.workingHours = 0;
        this.startUpCount = 0;
        this.errorCount = 0;
        this.feedbackTime = 0;
        this.safeToRestart = 0;
        this.unAckedError = 0;
        this.timeSchedules = [];
    }

    getValueFromDatabase(variableNameInDatabase)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "databaseValuesEnquiry.php",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            data:{getDatabaseVariableValue:1 ,"variableNameInDatabase":variableNameInDatabase,"databaseTableName":this.databaseTableName},
            success:function(response)
            {
                return response;
            }
        })
    }

    updateUIFromDatabase()
    {
        this.control = this.getValueFromDatabase("control");
        this.statusOfPump = this.getValueFromDatabase("statusOfPump");
        this.feedback = this.getValueFromDatabase("feedback");
        this.motorPTC = 0;
        this.dryRunProtection = 0;
        this.workingHours = 0;
        this.startUpCount = this.getValueFromDatabase("startUpCount");
        this.errorCount = 0;
        this.feedbackTime = 0;
        this.safeToRestart = 0;
        this.unAckedError = 0;
        this.timeSchedules = [];
    }

}

pump1 =new PumpBasic("pump1", "pump1settingstry");
pump1.getValueFromDatabase("workingHours");
pump1.updateUIFromDatabase();
console.log("startUpCount: ", pump1.startUpCount);
```

Comment: Do not use `async: false`!

Comment: And still, your `return` statement is placed inside the `success` callback not in the `getValueFromDatabase` scope, that's why the latter still returns `undefined`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

getValueFromDatabase method exists a return command but it's in a callback function. so it does not actually return a value for the getValueFromDatabase method, it returns response for the success callback. you should try something like below:

```
    getValueFromDatabase(variableNameInDatabase)
    {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: "databaseValuesEnquiry.php",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            data:{getDatabaseVariableValue:1 ,"variableNameInDatabase":variableNameInDatabase,"databaseTableName":this.databaseTableName},
            success:function(response)
            {
                result = response;
            }
        })
        return result;
    }
```

you can see the difference here: [ajax sample](https://codepen.io/salihtopcu/pen/abvyxjd?editors=0011)

Answer (score -1):

Lets take a look into this piece of code:

```
updateUIFromDatabase()
    {
        this.control = this.getValueFromDatabase("control");
        this.statusOfPump = this.getValueFromDatabase("statusOfPump");
        this.feedback = this.getValueFromDatabase("feedback");
        this.motorPTC = 0;
        this.dryRunProtection = 0;
        this.workingHours = 0;
        this.startUpCount = this.getValueFromDatabase("startUpCount");
        this.errorCount = 0;
        this.feedbackTime = 0;
        this.safeToRestart = 0;
        this.unAckedError = 0;
        this.timeSchedules = [];
    }
```

Here you call `getValueFromDatabase` several times. I never worked directly with `jQuery` but this block

```
return $.ajax({
            url: "databaseValuesEnquiry.php",
            method: "GET",
            async: false,
            data:{getDatabaseVariableValue:1 ,"variableNameInDatabase":variableNameInDatabase,"databaseTableName":this.databaseTableName},
            success:function(response)
            {
                return response;
            }
        })
```

indicates you are doing a request to the backend. Well, javascript is like fast, like super fast. You send a request to your backend and when it returns the rest of the code already executed. That's why you get undefined.

The function `getValueFromDatabase` will return a `Promise` (you can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Well, since it returns a promise (something that will happen in the future) you need to make the calls, wait for them to resolve and then do the rest of the things you need to do.

In this case it would look something like:

```
public async updateUIFromDatabase()
    {
        this.control = await this.getValueFromDatabase("control");
        this.statusOfPump = await this.getValueFromDatabase("statusOfPump");
        this.feedback = await this.getValueFromDatabase("feedback");
        this.motorPTC = 0;
        this.dryRunProtection = 0;
        this.workingHours = 0;
        this.startUpCount = await this.getValueFromDatabase("startUpCount");
        this.errorCount = 0;
        this.feedbackTime = 0;
        this.safeToRestart = 0;
        this.unAckedError = 0;
        this.timeSchedules = [];
    }
```

The `await` keyword is just a keyword to say to the javascript engine: 'Hey man, could you please stop the execution of this code until this promise is resolved?'

If you would like to learn more about the `await` keyword you can read it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

I hope this wasn't lenghty but I hope you could understand a little bit about promises

Comment: "*The function getValueFromDatabase will return a Promise*" - no, why would it? It's not written to do so.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I noticed that and added the `return` keyword to give the hint to OP. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Hello Charlie,

Correct, but in my case i use the async: false property of the Ajax request whitch means the code will actually wait to get the response.

Comment: @Vangde If you absolutely wanted to use `async: false` (which you shouldn't), you should not be using a `success` callback at all. `$.ajax` will just return the value, or throw an exception.

Comment: `public async updateUIFromDatabase() ` returns 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'async'' error